# Problems with insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm

I have tried to write an insertion sort algorithm, which I thought should have worked but it does not.

```
int [] array = {108, 10, 45, 67, 108, 23, 29, 108, 48, 67,902, 2, 32, 74, 108, 902};

for(out = 1; out < array.length; out++) {
    min = array[out];
    in = out - 1;

    while(array[in] > min && in > 0) {
        array[in + 1] = array[in];
        in--;
    }
    array[in] = min;   
}
```

The output I get when it is run:

```
32 45 45 45 45 48 67 74 108 108 108 108 902 902 902 902
```

The expected output is:

```
2, 10, 23, 29, 32, 45, 48, 67, 67, 74, 108, 108, 108, 108, 902, 902
```

Comment: What is the Input and what is the expected result?

Comment: looks like sorted to me

Comment: Some may think that what you're doing wrong is writing your own sort when Java provides a perfectly adequate `Array.sort()` :-) In any case, there's absolutely *no* way we can tell if your output is faulty without knowing the input. Suggest you add that before the question gets closed and/or deleted.

Comment: Edit with expected output.

Comment: The code is perfectly fine with a tiny issue. Its the value of "in". Try debugging the program for each step and you will find the issue.

Comment: Try this [here](https://ideone.com/zHN86X)

Comment: `with a tiny issue` - let me add a minuscule one: `min` not meaning minimum, and no other meaning given.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [here](https://ideone.com/lqd7ih)

```
    int[] array = {902, 902, 48, 108, 32, 45, 45, 67, 74, 108, 45, 45, 3, 108, 902, 108, 902};
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        int x = array[i];
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array[j-1] > x) {
            array[j] = array[j-1];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        array[j] = x;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: An easier way to print an array is: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Comment: Haven't programmed in Java for a while so I drew a complete blank. Had tried array.toString() but wasn't working :P

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
 *  Insertion sort O(n^2)
 * @author shohanur rahaman
 */
public class insertionSort {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int[] ara = {5,32,99,0,6,-12,19};

        for(int i=1;i<ara.length;i++){
            int tmp = ara[i]; 
            int j=i-1;
            while(j>=0 && tmp<ara[j]){
                ara[j+1] = ara[j];
                j--;
            }
            ara[j+1] = tmp;
        } // end parent loop

        for(int i=0;i<ara.length;i++){
            System.out.print(ara[i]+ " ");
        }
    }
}
```